# What is fill-stroke in SVG styling?

Tags: svg, styling

I have an SVG drawing that was created by someone else using Inkscape that is rich with  styling similar to this example:

```
<g style="fill:none;fill-stroke:#666666;stroke-width:0.1;">
<path d="M 65.840951,184.29062 V 191.9" />
<path d="m 55.651403,185.86413 v 5.72039" />
<path d="m 53.543313,182.97155 v 2.68529" />
</g>
```

I don't know what fill-stroke is and a google search produces no results. What is it please?

Comment: It's a typo, it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Quite likely the author meant `stroke: #666666` (setting a stroke color). Now you will see strokes with the default color black. A simple search/replace might help to get the desired stroke colors.